# Java: PSQL Exception: syntax error at or near "$1"

Tags: java, postgresql

I am building a query string "filters" and then calling it using the @Query annotation.

I am getting a `PSQLException: syntax error at or near "$1"` when trying to execute the query

My current code is:

```
String QUERY = "?1";
@Query(value=QUERY, nativeQuery = true)
List<CustomData> findAllByFilters(String filter);
```

I've tried switching "?1" to "$1", and I've tried without quotations.

Comment: It's unclear which `@Query` annotation you are using, but the problem is surely that neither `"?1"` nor `"$1"` is a valid query in PSQL or any other relevant query language I know.  It's as if the entire body of this present question were just "42".  What would that mean?  How could we respond, other than with some variation on "that doesn't make sense"?

Comment: @John It's JPA.

Comment: Try something like `@Query("select t from my_table t where t.some_column = ?1")`

Comment: @Bohemian I am able to get that to work, but the reason I am trying to just use"?1" as the query is because depending on the request, there could be a different number of columns to filter by. So the query could look like  `@Query("select t from my_table t where t.some_column = ?1")` or `@Query("select t from my_table t where t.some_column = ?1 and t.some_column = ?2")`. So I am building the entire query out in a function and passing it into `@Query`

Comment: @Bohemian, JPA has an ordinary interface named `Query`, but no `@Query` annotation.  If I had to guess, I would go with Spring, but I should not have to guess.

Comment: @Caroline It doesn't work like that. If you want to build the whole query, down shift to using a `PreparedStatement`, or if the options are not too varied, create several Queries and decide which one to call within a public wrapper method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you can pass as a query parameter is a constant value like `42`, `'string'` or `'2023-07-26'`. You cannot pass table or column names or bigger parts of an SQL statement like a `WHERE` clause or the complete statement.

You can construct the query string (avoid SQL injection!), then create a `java.sql.Statement`.